# offline/online data sync in firestore - Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to develop a web app using `Laravel` and `vue.js` where I can sync data from firestore even if I am offline. I have seen in the features of [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) that it provides this feature. But I dont know how to this feature into my project. I have cloned [suhasrkms/laravel-with-firestore](https://github.com/suhasrkms/laravel-with-firestore) for Firestore in Laravel. But main problem i am facing is i dont know how to add offline code/persistence. I tried to add the code in resources/js/offline-persistence.js which is provided in firestore doc. I have tried to add code as well in my blade file.
Kindly provide me the solution, your reply will be valuable for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    firebase.firestore().enablePersistence()
        .catch((err) => alert(Something failed for enablePersistence, code: ${err.code}));

    firebase.firestore().collection('test')
        .onSnapshot(snaps => {
            if (snaps.empty) { return; }
            const preDataElm = document.getElementById("preData");
            while (preDataElm.firstChild) {
                preDataElm.removeChild(preDataElm.firstChild);
            }
            let list = snaps.docs.map(snap => {
                return {id: snap.id, ...snap.data()};
            });
            let newElm = document.createElement("PRE");
            newElm.innerText = JSON.stringify(list, null, 2);

            return preDataElm.appendChild(newElm);
        });

    function tryMe() {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHtml = "";
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection('test')
            .add({test: new Date().toString()})
            .then((docRef) => alert(Data inserted successfuly ID: ${docRef.id}));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Comment: Thanks for keep asking, i was not able apply it so i alternatively applied Laravel's Chache package. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835844/getting-error-neterr-cert-authority-invalid
Can you plz check this question, if you know any solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

To  add offline code/persistence , you need to enable or disable offline persistence while initializing  Cloud Firestore, as stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence):

> - For Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default. To disable persistence, set the PersistenceEnabled option to false.
> - For the web, offline persistence is disabled by default.To enable  persistence, call the enablePersistence method. Cloud Firestore's  cache isn't  automatically cleared between sessions.Consequently, if your web app handles sensitive information, make sure to ask the user if they're on a trusted device before enabling persistence.

You can also refer to the  stackoverflow [case1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48418352/offline-online-mode-for-data-sync-firestore) and [case2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352235/google-cloud-firestore-sync-devices-data-in-local-network-no-internet-temporall) where a similar issue has been faced by the OP which got resolved by setting up the persistence as:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```